# Get attribute name on exception in converter

Tags: python-attrs

When an error occurred in a validator it is passible to add a name of the failed attribute to an error message, because this name passed to the validator.

But if an error occurred in a converter I see no way to get name of failed attribute, e.g.

```
@attr.s
class Test:
    attr1 = attr.ib(converter=int, validator=attr.validators.in_([1,2,3]))
    attr2 = attr.ib(converter=int, validator=attr.validators.in_([1,2,3]))

>>> Test('1', '2a')

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2a'
```

How I can handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly that's currently not possible, since `converter` only receives the value and nothing else. The code that attrs produces in your case is

```py
self.attr1 = int(attr1)
```

I think this is tangentially related to https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/146.